# jsfiddle Amchart example not working

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle, amcharts

I have implemented this AmChart example from codepen:
http://codepen.io/amcharts/pen/e44996db5f40cf18b586f089a9988d32

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
```

(code above is required by stackoverflow as I have posted a codepen.io link)

in jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3j9pnr6v/

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
```

(code above is required by stackoverflow as I have posted a jsfiddle link)

I cannot get it to produce any chart - the "result" pane remains empty - any suggestions?

Comment: if you inspect the console log you will see your issue 'Uncaught ReferenceError: weekendGuides is not defined'

Comment: add `var chartData = weekendGuides = [];` at the top , it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look at the console log in chrome you will see it says your error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: weekendGuides is not defined

categoryAxis: {
      guides: weekendGuides << this is not defined.
    },
```

what does `weekendGuides` need to be set to.. that is where your problem is set that to a value and it will work.

Tip always look at the console log to see if it tells you whats wrong with the code.. normally with javascript it will let you know the issue. :)